# Exception calling "ReadToEnd" with "0" argument(s): "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed."

Tags: powershell, encryption, aes

I'm trying to get simple encryption/decryption working with Aes in PowerShell, but I keep getting an exception when trying to decrypt the output.

I get the exception:

> Exception calling "ReadToEnd" with "0" argument(s): "Padding is
>   invalid and cannot be removed."

Any ideas?

```
Function Aes-Encrypt( $plainTextBytes ){

    $key = "vqMcLYelBxefzIAMpO9Q/Q=="
    $plainText = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($plainTextBytes)

    #Use the AES cipher and represent it as an object.
    $AES = New-Object "System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged"
    $AES.Mode = [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]::CBC
    $AES.Padding = [System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]::PKCS7
    $AES.BlockSize = 128
    $AES.KeySize = 128
    $IV = $AES.IV
    #$AES.Key = $key

    # Creates a MemoryStream to do the encryption in 
    $ms = new-Object IO.MemoryStream 

    # Creates the new Cryptology Stream --> Outputs to $MS or Memory Stream 
    $cs = new-Object Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream $ms,$AES.CreateEncryptor(),"Write" 

    #Writes the string in the Cryptology Stream
    $cs.Write($IV, 0, 16)
    $cs.Write($plainText, 0, $plainText.Length);
    $cs.FlushFinalBlock();

    # Stops the Cryptology Stream
    $cs.Close()

    # Stops writing to Memory
    $ms.Close()

    # Clears the IV and HASH from memory to prevent memory read attacks
    $cs.Clear()

    # Takes the MemoryStream and puts it to an array
    [byte[]]$rmesult = $ms.ToArray()
    # return $ms.ToArray()
    # Converts the array from Base 64 to a string and returns
    return [Convert]::ToBase64String($rmesult)

}

Function Aes-Decrypt( $DecryptData ){

    $key = "vqMcLYelBxefzIAMpO9Q/Q=="
    #$plainText = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($plainTextBytes)

    # Create a COM Object for RijndaelManaged Cryptography 
    #$r = new-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged 

    #Use the AES cipher and represent it as an object.
    $AES = New-Object "System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged"
    $AES.Mode = [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]::CBC
    $AES.Padding = [System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]::PKCS7
    $AES.BlockSize = 128
    $AES.KeySize = 128
    $IV = $AES.IV
    #$AES.Key = $key

    $cipherTextBytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($DecryptData)

    # Creates a MemoryStream to do the encryption in 
    $ms = new-Object IO.MemoryStream @(,$cipherTextBytes)

    # Creates the new Cryptology Stream --> Outputs to $MS or Memory Stream 
    $cs = new-Object Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream $ms,$AES.CreateDecryptor(),"Read" 

    # Read the new decrypted stream 
    $sr = new-Object IO.StreamReader $cs 

    # Return from the function the stream 
    Write-Output $sr.ReadToEnd() 

    # Stops the stream     
    $sr.Close() 

    # Stops the crypology stream
    $cs.Close()

    # Stops writing to Memory
    $ms.Close()

    $cs.Clear()

    # Takes the MemoryStream and puts it to an array
    return $ms.ToArray()



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message:

> "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed."

is a general symptom of the encryption not working and can occur if you don't use the **same key and IV on both encrypt & decrypt**, or if the encrypted message have been altered somehow.

In your code you don't seem to set your key, and you don't generate a random IV. Also you seem to encrypt the IV in the crypto stream which won't give the effect you properly expect.

You need to generate a random IV and pass it along with your encrypted data in an un-encrypted form (it don't need to be secret). Your decrypter then needs to read the IV and initialize the AES-cipher with it before starting decrypting.